# How to set title with data from included PHP file

Tags: php, html

I have a website with a template page that is something like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{TITLE}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "header"> ... </div>
            <?php include 'content.php'; ?>
        <div id = "footer"> ... </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then content.php would look something like this

```
<?php 
    $title = "xx";
    #other php code here
?>
<p> more content </p>
```

My question is whether there is some way to set this up so that I am able to set the title from the file included in the middle of the page (without using javascript). I know that most people suggest including it at the top but if I were to do that the html would be at the top instead of between the header and the footer. I've wracked my brains for a while and I haven't really figured out a good way to do this (and there are a variety of possible files to be included; content.php is just an example, so I really do need some way to do this dynamically). I want to avoid putting too much code outside of the template. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'content.php';
$content = ob_get_clean();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?=htmlspecialchars($title)?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "header"> ... </div>
            <?=$content?>
        <div id = "footer"> ... </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, this will execute any PHP code in content.php (ex `readfile()`) and store the output until the echo in the body, correct? Also, if I were to call this in a function, what would be the scope of `$title`? Would it follow `$content` if I returned it?

Comment: @HenryC Yes. It's the same as without `ob_start` except that it saves the output. `$title` and `$content` are separate. They don't follow each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using a templating engine or not (something like Laravel's Blade templates allow for this, I believe), but assuming you are using straight PHP, I have found the most efficient way to do this is to approach from the opposite direction and include the template file in each of my content files.

For example, I may have template.php, which has multiple functions, like this:

```
<?php

function createHeader($title, $keywords) {
    //echo or <<<EOD your header with the set variables
}

function createFooter(...) { ... } //etc
```

And then, in my 'child' files, I would do:

```
<?php include('template.php'); ?>

<?php createHeader("My Website Front Page!", "fun, good times, joy"); ?>

<h1>My page content</h1>
<p>Content goes here</p>

<?php createFooter(...); ?>
```

This is a different structure from what you were attempting, though, and may not retain your intended structure.